# Basis for the subspace w spanned by ${v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My textbook doesn't contain any solution to the answer so I was wondering if my answer is right.

Let $$v_1 =\begin{bmatrix}
            1\\
           -3 \\
            4
  \end{bmatrix}, 
v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
    6 &\\
    2\\
   -1
  \end{bmatrix},
v_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
     2 &\\
    -2\\
     3
  \end{bmatrix},
\text { and } v_4 = \begin{bmatrix}
     -4 &\\
     -8\\
      9
  \end{bmatrix}$$

Find a basis for the subspace $W$ spanned by ${v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4}$?

What I did is that I reduced the matrix:

$$W = \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 6 & 2 &-4\\
    -3 & 2 &-2 &-8\\
     4 &-1 & 3 & 9
  \end{bmatrix}$$

then I reduced it rref --> $$W = \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 8 &-2\\
     0 & 1 & \frac{4}{20} &-1\\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}$$

therefore the basis for the subspace $W$ spanned by ${v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4}$. would be $B= {\begin{bmatrix}
     1 \\
    -3  \\
     4 
  \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
     6 \\
     2 \\
     -1 
  \end{bmatrix} }$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it seems correct. You can verify that indeed $v_3,v_4\in{\rm span}(v_1,v_2)$.

Comment: Yes it is correct. Minor mistakes in your row reduction but doesn't affect the final results. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%5B%5B1%2C6%2C2%2C-4%5D%2C%5B-3%2C2%2C-2%2C-8%5D%2C%5B4%2C-1%2C3%2C9%5D%5D) for full row reduction.

Comment: O thank you, I didn't even notice that v3 is half of that of v4. Thanks XD.

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered in comments:

> Yes, it seems correct. You can verify that indeed $v_3,v_4\in \text{span}(v_1,v_2)$. –  Berci Jan 27 at 21:11

and

> Yes it is correct. Minor mistakes in your row reduction but doesn't affect the final results. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+[[1%2C6%2C2%2C-4]%2C[-3%2C2%2C-2%2C-8]%2C[4%2C-1%2C3%2C9]]) for full row reduction. –  John Habert Jan 27 at 21:16

Answer (score 0):

The pivot columns of the RREF correspond to columns of the original matrix which will form a basis for the column space.  Thus your answer is correct.  (Row-reduction, while it can change the column space, doesnt change the relations between the columns).